# MS Access getting Inconsistent Results from SQLServer Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

I'm having a bizarre problem with a project I'm working on for a client. I have an Access 2007 database getting data from SQLServer stored procedures. Several SPs are working correctly. One SP was working, then we added a field to it. That field had already existed within the source table.

Originally, the table would give me a school_code(key) and a grade_name. We added a sequence number, so that the list of grade_names would be displayed in a particular order. Before we added the sequence number, I would get the list I expected...for a given school, I get a list like 'PK', 'K', '1', '2', etc.

After adding the sequence number, I get the same number of items in the list, but every item in the list is the same for a given school, i.e. they are all 'PK' and they all have a sequence number of '1'.

When I view the stored procedure using SQL tools, the list looks right. When I view it through Access, the list just displays duplicates down the line, for a given school. Going from school to school, the grade_name will display the first grade_name for that school. Every value down the sequence column is a '1'.

Any thoughts on how to attack this???
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like the issue was associated with the DISTINCT keyword. When I included it, I got the answers I expected. When I added the clause to "ORDER BY sequence", I was prohibited from using DISTINCT; the two can't be used together.

To solve this, I dropped the ORDER BY, placed the results into a 2-dimensional array, then sorted the array and used that. Kind of a kludge, as I don't understand why dropping DISTNCT was causing problems...